# Different definition of discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, definition

In our lecture the professor defines a discrete random variable by

> Let be $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},p)$ a discrete probability space (where the $\mathcal{F}$ is simply the power set). Then, a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a discrete random variable.

I am wondering if this definition is too narrow or maybe wrong?

If we consider the uncountable probability space
$$
\left([0,1],\left\{\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right),\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right],\left[0,1\right],\emptyset\right\},p\right)
$$
and a function
$$
Y:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}.
$$
Then, this function won't be a discrete random variable which would be kinda strange...

Is there any reason for defining a discrete random variable the way our professor did?

(See also [Definition of Discrete Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2097166/579544), but it doesn't fully answer my question)

Comment: What is $p$? If $p$ is just a number, what are you taking as underlying measure.

Comment: @JasonSwanson, yes $\Omega$ must be countable

Comment: @WilliamM. here $p$ assigns a probability to each element of $\Omega$.

Comment: Ah! So that is what you got wrong: $p$ is a function defined on the sigma algebra; not on $\Omega.$ Therefore, $p(x)$ is only defined for $x \in \{[0,\frac{1}{2}), [\frac{1}{2},1]\}$ or $x$ trivial (i.e. empty or total). In this case, you can rename your space as $\Omega = \{0^*,1^*\},$ with the power set, now $0^*$ represents $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $1^*$ represents $[\frac{1}{2},1].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you give can be viewed as a theorem (if $p$ then $q$) rather than a definition of $q$:

**Theorem:** Fix probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. If $\Omega$ is a finite or countably infinite sample space then every random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ must be a discrete random variable.

**Proof:** Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. If $\Omega$ is finite or countably infinite then the image $X(\Omega)$ is finite or countably infinite. $\Box$

The nice thing about random variables is that, once you know their distribution, you do not need to know the sample space. **Most people would define a binary-valued Bernoulli random variable to be a discrete random variable, even if the sample space is uncountably infinite.** If your professor is suggesting that all discrete random variables have finite or countably infinite sample spaces, then your professor is "cutting corners" for convenience.  Such a definition is not satisfactory because it would never allow a probability space to have two random variables $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $X$ is discrete and $Y$ is continuous. You can see the professor is already cutting corners by assuming the sigma algebra is just the full power set. [This is not necessarily bad: Most of the basic probability concepts can be developed on finite or countably infinite sample spaces and using the power set sigma algebra. But one must use uncountably infinite sample spaces (and more sophisticated sigma algebras) when treating more advanced things such as continuous random variables and/or infinite sequences of random variables.]

---

There are various definitions of "discrete random variable" that are used: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space (the sample space $\Omega$ can be uncountably infinite).

**Definition 1:** A random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be **discrete** if the image $X(\Omega)$ is a finite or countably infinite set.

**Definition 2 (not equivalent):** A random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be **discrete** if there is a finite or countably infinite subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $P[X \in A]=1$.

It is easy to prove that if a random variable satisfies definition 1 then it also satisfies definition 2. Thus, the proof of the theorem I stated in the first part of my answer holds under **either** of these two definitions of "discrete random variable."

Of course, definition 2 is more general and it is possible for a random variable to satisfy definition 2 without satisfying definition 1: Consider the probability space $([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the standard Borel measure (length) on the unit interval. Let $V$ be any uncountably infinite and Borel measurable subset of $[0,1]$ that has $\lambda(V)=0$. Define the random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$ X(\omega) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \mbox{ if $\omega < 1/2$ and $\omega \notin V$} \\
1 & \mbox{ if $\omega\geq 1/2$ and $\omega \notin V$} \\
\omega & \mbox{ if $\omega \in V$} 
\end{array}\right.$$
Then $X(\Omega) = V \cup \{0,1\}$ is uncountably infinite so $X$ does not satisfy definition 1. But $X$ satisfies definition 2 with $A=\{0,1\}$. The distribution of $X$ is $Bernoulli(1/2)$.

Comment: I'd say Definition 2 is the usual one, many discrete random processes have uncountable sample space (e.g. random walk), yet they are definitely discrete.

Comment: Both definitions 1 and 2 allow for uncountable sample spaces. The image $X(\Omega)=\{X(\omega) : \omega \in \Omega\}$ can be a finite or countably infinite set even if $\Omega$ is uncountable. For example, take the function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $X(\omega)=0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your question because it can be one of several, all of which are similar. So, I am going to answer several general questions related to your own.

**Claim 1:** If $S$ is a discrete set and $(p_\lambda)_{\lambda \in S}$ is a family of non-negative numbers, then $\mu(L) = \sum\limits_{\lambda \in L} p_\lambda$ define a measure on $\mathscr{P}(S).$

**Claim 2:** If $S$ is an interval, then there is no way to define Lebesgue measure over $\mathscr{P}(S).$

**Claim 3:** Let $(X, \mathscr{X}),$ $(Y, \mathscr{Y})$ two measurable spaces and $f:X \to Y$ a measurable function. Let $f^{-1}(\mathscr{Y})$ be $\{f^{-1}(B) \mid B \in \mathscr{Y}\}.$ Then $f^{-1}(\mathscr{Y}) \subset \mathscr{X}$ is a sigma field and $f$ is measurable relative to the measurable spaces $(X, f^{-1}(\mathscr{Y})),$ $(Y, \mathscr{Y});$ furthermore, this is the minimal sigma field that makes $f$ measurable.

**Finally,** the previous three claims show that there are several ways to define discrete random variables. The particular way I learnt it is different for your own. For me a discrete random variable is a random variable with discrete range (upto nullity). That is, there exists a discrete set $S$ such that $\mathbf{P}(X \in S) = 1.$ Considering $p_\lambda = \mathbf{P}(X = \lambda)$ for $\lambda \in S$ you get what we have in **Claim 1**; by taking pre-images, you get a definition through **Claim 3** (which is much more similar yo your own). Note however, that in **Claim 3** what $(X, \mathscr{X})$ is doesn't matter as much, while your definition impose a severe restriction. The point a random variable is that it transforms the "abstract" domain $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbf{P})$ into a more familiar $([a,b], \mathscr{B}([a,b]), F_X).$

Comment: I had a typo in my question, hopefully it's clear now

Comment: The definition your professor gave is acceptable, although I did answer your question.